# how do i plot a vertical line in pine script whenever the 50 ema crosses up or down the 200 ema?

Tags: algorithm, pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I keep getting mismatch. whats wrong with it? I want to be able to plot a very faint vertical line indicating that the security is either in an up or down trend. someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Shauryam_or
indicator(title='EMA Cross 50/200', overlay=true)
short = ta.ema(close, 50)
long = ta.ema(close, 200)
plot(short, color=color.new(color.red, 0))
plot(long, color=color.new(color.blue, 0))
plot(ta.cross(short, long) ? short : na, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=4)

if ta.cross(short, long) 
    line.new(bar_index, 0, bar_index, 1e6)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).